# python input mixed data types in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input

I just started learning python a few days ago and have a quick question I can't find an answer to:

How would you ask for items to add to a list while keeping their data type?

if i do this:

```
def itemType(anyList):
    for i in range(len(anyList)):
        print(type(anyList[i]))

exampleList = []

while True:
    newItem = input('Add item to list? "NO" to end input.)
    if newItem == 'NO':
        break
    else:
        exampleList.append(input())

itemType(exampleList)
```

Obviously all the list items are string values. Is there a way to ask for input but keep string, integer, float or whatever data type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Comment: Welcome to SO. The input will always be stored as a string. How would the computer know, if your `2` will be used as a number or a string? You have to convert it (or use try/except to convert it) in the datatype you expect from the input. [See also here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) Happy coding.

Comment: If you want the user to be able to add any valid Python literal, look at [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval); their `input` is **always** a string in Python 3.x. But it's not really very clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: There is no keeping of the data type. The user enters strings, fundamentally, bytes of information. You can choose various ways of interpreting that information. Using `eval` (or more safely, `ast.literal_eval`) would interpret the input strings as Python code (or in the latter case, only valid Python literals)

Answer (score 0):

You could try casting to each variable type:

```
try:
  newItem = int(newItem)
except ValueError:
  newItem = float(newItem)
except ValueError:
  pass #keep as string
```

Comment: It's not a valid python code. For strings, you'll get "during handling of the above exception, another exception occurred".

Answer (score 0):

You could try with python build in function `isnumeric`.

Here is what it look like:

```
def itemType(anyList):
    for i in range(len(anyList)):
        print(type(anyList[i]))

exampleList = []

while True:
    newItem = input('Add item to list? "NO" to end input.')
    if newItem == 'NO':
        break
    else:
      if(newItem.isnumeric()):
        exampleList.append(int(newItem))
      else:
        exampleList.append(newItem)

itemType(exampleList)
```

It only check for `integer` and `string/float`.

Comment: Your program does not cast negative integers to int